# Getting Exception at console: Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not set, which is probably not what is desired.

Tags: java, xsd, tomcat6, xml-validation

Actually, i Have deployed my web-application on tomcat and when i start the application i am getting the following exception at console:

Warning: validation was turned on but an org.xml.sax.ErrorHandler was not
set, which is probably not what is desired.  Parser will use a default
ErrorHandler to print the first 10 errors.  Please call
the 'setErrorHandler' method to fix this.

Note:The Same Application runs on WebLogic but Issue is coming in tomcat.

Can anyone tell a solution?

Is there any dependency of the XMLSchema on the application-server?

Comment: Is that the exact error message? Is there any further information surrounding it or in the Tomcat logs?